# Laravel 5 Resourceful Routes Plus Middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware

Is it possible to add middleware to all or some items of a resourceful route?

For example...

```php
<?php

Route::resource('quotes', 'QuotesController');
```

Furthermore, if possible, I wanted to make all routes aside from `index` and `show` use the `auth` middleware. Or would this be something that needs to be done within the controller?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

In `QuotesController` constructor you can then use:

```
$this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['index','show']]);
```

Reference: [Controller middleware in Laravel 5](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#controller-middleware)

Comment: Thanks! Wasn't sure if this was something that could be done within the resource call but doesn't seem to be from what I've looked at so far

Comment: I need to pass other arguments to the Middleware, is it possible from this?

Comment: @activatedgeek If you have new question, ask one

Comment: what about when using Route::apiResources([]) ? did not find how to add a middleware for all apiResources at once?

Answer (score 66):

You could use Route Group coupled with Middleware concept:
http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function()
{
    Route::resource('todo', 'TodoController', ['only' => ['index']]);
});
```

Comment: about a year old but since I'm trying to do the same shouldn't it be `Route::resource('todo', 'TodoController', ['except' => ['index']]);` to exclude only index from auth middleware?

Comment: It depends on what you want your auth controller on. The general idea is still relevant and so is the link provided, IMO.

Answer (score 6):

In Laravel with PHP 7, it didn't work for me with multi-method exclude until wrote

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
        
Route::resource('categories', 'CategoryController', ['except' => 'show,index']);
});
```

maybe that helps someone.

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE FOR LARAVEL 8.x**

web.php:

```
Route::resource('quotes', 'QuotesController');
```

in your controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
        $this->middleware('auth')->except(['index','show']);
        // OR
        $this->middleware('auth')->only(['store','update','edit','create']);
}
```

Reference: [Controller Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#controller-middleware)

Answer (score 2):

Been looking for a better solution for Laravel 5.8+.

Here's what i did:

Apply middleware to resource, except those who you do not want the middleware to be applied. (Here index and show)

```
 Route::resource('resource', 'Controller', [
            'except' => [
                'index',
                'show'
            ]
        ])
        ->middleware(['auth']);
```

Then, create the resource routes that were except in the first one. So index and show.

```
Route::resource('resource', 'Controller', [
        'only' => [
            'index',
            'show'
        ]
    ]);
```