# 'can' middleware with Route::resource in Laravel

Tags: laravel, routes, authorization, middleware, user-roles

I want to apply authorization check on all my routes for a resource. For example:

- **Admin** can create **Doctor**
- **Admin** can update **Doctor**
- **Admin** can view **Doctor(s)**
- **Admin** can delete **Doctor**

Can I achieve this by applying [**"can"** middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization#via-middleware) on resource routes, something like:

```
Route::resource('doctors', 'DoctorsController')->middleware('can:*,App\Doctor');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In DoctorsController constructor you can use:

```
$this->middleware('can:<something>,App\Doctor');
```

[Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28729228/laravel-5-route-resources-middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28729228/laravel-5-route-resources-middleware)

Comment: I've already checked the linked question but actually here I don't want specific permission but I need **can** middleware on all permissions for the resource. So can I use it like `->middleware('can:*, App\Doctor')` with or without controller???

Answer (score -1):

```
Route::resource('doctors', 'DoctorsController', ['middleware' => ['middleware1', 'middleware2', 'middleware3']]);
```

Comment: does this mean I have to write each route separately with can like `'DoctorsController', ['middleware' => ['can:create', 'can:update', ... ]]);` **???** 

Comment: You can create a custom middleware for example named `ManageDoctors` and inside that middleware check for all permissions `create, update, delete...` and then put `MangeDoctors` middleware on the resource route.

Comment: please try to add more info to the answer to be clear about the solution