# How to protect only specific routes of my controller?

Tags: laravel

So I have a Resource controller and it's route defined as below:

```
Route::resource('product', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProdutoController')->middleware('auth');
```

But, I wanted to not-logged in user to be able to acces the "show" method inside that controller. How can I apply the "auth" middleware to every method inside the controller except the "show" method?

Comment: **you can find your solution from here:**
[more details...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28729228/laravel-5-resourceful-routes-plus-middleware)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your ProdutoController you can use the construct method to apply the authentication middleware and except some routes like this:

```
/**
     * Instantiate a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth')->except(['index', 'show']); 
    }
```